# Symfony - app_dev my ipv6 added

Tags: php, symfony, development-environment, ipv6

I'm trying to give access to the dev environment of my Symfony2 application for my ip.

**web/app_dev.php**

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        'xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx', // My ipv6
        '::1',
    ))
) {
```

It works with my ipv4 but not with my ipv6.

How can it be explained ?
How can I debug this ?

Comment: I think it is better to protect the `app_dev/php` file with HTACCESS

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit more secure, but here I'm just trying to use the standard way it's designed on Symfony. Do you think we should override this security with htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, I think. Symfony2 hasn't really a standard way of securing the `app_dev.php` file. It is maybe a little bit more secure, but I just think it is the place to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, to fix this issue I modified the **app_dev.php** by insering a code that show your IP from serveur point of view !  :)

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
$monip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.<br>Your IP is '.$monip);
```

And Finally I added the shown IP in the IP array in app_dev.php file throught ftp.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
|| !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', 'yourIP_HERE')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
```

)